# Ag grid react: How to specify start page, pagination

Tags: ag-grid-react

I'd like to know id there is a way to open an ag-grid on the last page upon start. The page size is 10000 and the extra rows should go in the first page, not the last. (So the last page and everything else except for the first page should have 10000 rows)

I've done some research online and didn't really find what I was looking for. I tried implementing the getRows method below but the results are the same.

```
getRows (params) {

    // Use startRow and endRow for sending pagination to Backend
    params.startPage = (this.state.fileNames.length / 1000);
    params.endPage = 1;


    this.apiService().subscribe(response => {

      params.successCallback(
        response.data, response.totalRecords
      );

    })
  }
```